# Sub menu disappearing on hover

Tags: html, css, menu

My sub menu is disappearing on hover. When I hover over the menu item it appears but when i try to go to the sub menu item.. it goes away. Any idea why?

I have tried doing this:

```
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block !important;
}
```

But i still have the same issue. Any help will be appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Testing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Testing 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav ul {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #7d7a7a;
}

.nav ul ul li {
  border-right: none;
}

.nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 80%;
}

.nav ul li a i {
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block !important;
}

.nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  height: auto;
  top: 34px;
  padding: 13px 10px;
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background-color: #47a3da;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dykwgwau/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because there is a gap between the dropdown and the button.

You need to  get rid of any margin and top for the dropdown to be right under the button.

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/dykwgwau/1/)

```
.nav > ul {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you parent `li` and its dropdown menu-item has extra space between them, dropdown `ul` losses the event of `.nav ul li ul li:hover`. To make it work,

simply adjust the vertical distance b/w parent and its dropdown child menu-item

```
.nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  height: auto;
  top: 18px; /* Works fine on 18px*/
  padding: 13px 10px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hszpbmwk/)**